# how to define laravel 5.0 routes by means of directories

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I would like to do this thing with laravel 5.0.
I would have many routes.php files in some folders (like, under the app/ folder, I create a "linux" folder and a "windows" folder). Inside the two linux and windows folders, i put two routes.php files, with different routes (like, i don't know, they both have the route get('os') ).
What I want is that calling public/windows/os it is called the route os of the windows folder, and calling public/linux/os it is called the route os of the linux folder (basic polimorphism). 
I searched over and over and found nothing helpful. Do you have some advice?
Thanks.

Comment: [Well then...](http://youtu.be/0N90D68_NfQ?t=3s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply include the other route files in your main `routes.php` and put them inside route groups:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'windows'], function(){
    include app_path('windows/routes.php');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'linux'], function(){
    include app_path('linux/routes.php');
});
```

To reduce the duplicate code you can also use an array to configure your subdirectories:

```
$systems = ['windows', 'linux'];
foreach($systems as $os){
    Route::group(['prefix' => $os], function(){
        include app_path($os.'/routes.php');
    });
}
```